# Using nginx to simulate slow response time for testing purposes

Tags: nginx, jmeter, load-testing

I'm developing a facebook canvas application and I want to load-test it. I'm aware of the facebook restriction on automated testing, so I simulated the graph api calls by creating a fake web application served under nginx and altering my /etc/hosts to point graph.facebook.com to 127.0.0.1.

I'm using jmeter to load-test the application and the simulation is working ok. Now I want to simulate slow graph api responses and see how they affect my application. How can I configure nginx so that it inserts a delay to each request sent to the simulated graph.facebook.com application?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can slow the speed of localhost (network) by adding delay.
Use `ifconfig` command to see network device: on localhost it may be `lo` and on LAN its `eth0`.

- to add delay use this command (adding 1000ms delay on `lo` network device)

  `tc qdisc add dev lo root netem delay 1000ms`
- to change delay use this one

  `tc qdisc change dev lo root netem delay 1ms`
- to see current delay

  `tc qdisc show dev lo`
- and to remove delay

  `tc qdisc del dev lo root netem delay 1000ms`

Comment: Unfortunately, `tc` is only for Linux, but does not appear on OS X.

Answer (score 8):

My earlier answer works but it is more adapted to a case where all requests need to be slowed down. I've since had to come up with a solution that would allow me to turn on the rate limit only on a case-by-case basis, and came up with the following configuration. Make sure to read the entire answer before you use this, because there are important nuances to know.

```
    location / {
        if (-f somewhere/sensible/LIMIT) {
           echo_sleep 1;
           # Yes, we need this here too.
           echo_exec /proxy$request_uri;
        }

        echo_exec /proxy$request_uri;
    }

    location /proxy/ {
        internal;
        # Ultimately, all this goes to a Django server.
        proxy_pass http://django/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

**Important note: the presence or absence of forward slashes in the various paths makes a difference.** For instance, `proxy_pass http://django`, without a trailing slash, does *not* do the same thing as the line in the code above.

The principle of operation is simple. If the file `somewhere/sensible/LIMIT` exists, then requests that match `location /` are paused for one second before moving on. So in my test suite, when I want a network slowdown, I create the file, and when I want to remove the slowdown, I remove it. (And I have cleanup code that removes it between each test.) In theory I'd much prefer using variables for this than a file, but the problem is that variables are reinitialized with each request. So we cannot have a `location` block that would set a variable to turn the limit, and another to turn it off. (That's the first thing I tried, and it failed due to the lifetime of variables). It would probably be possible to use the Perl module or Lua to persist variables or fiddle with cookies, but I've decided not to go down these routes.

Important notes:

1. It is not a good idea to mix directives from the `echo` module (like `echo_sleep` and `echo_exec`) with the stock directives of nginx that result in the production of a response. I initially had `echo_sleep` together with `proxy_pass` and got bad results. That's why we have the `location /proxy/` block that segregates the stock directives from the `echo` stuff. (See this [issue](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module/issues/5) for a similar conflict that was resolved by splitting a block.)
2. The two `echo_exec` directives, inside and outside the `if`, are necessary due to how `if` works.
3. The `internal` directive prevents clients from directly requesting `/proxy/...` URLs.

Answer (score 4):

I've modified a nginx config to use `limit_req_zone` and `limit_req` to introduce delays. The following reduces the rate of service to 20 requests per second (`rate=20r/s`). I've set `burst=1000` so that my application would not get 503 responses.

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=20r/s;
    [...]
    server {
        [...]
        location / {
            limit_req zone=one burst=1000;
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html). I do not believe there is a way to specify a uniform delay using this method.